# What is onUnknownRoute in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I'm new to flutter, In MaterailApp Widget have an attribute called [onUnknownRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onUnknownRoute.html). What is the main use of onUnknownRoute?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In `flutter web`, when user manually key a undefine route, it can produce like `404` effect

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MaterialApp(    
    initialRoute: "/screen1",
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/screen1': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen1(),
      '/screen2': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen2(),
      '/screen3': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen3(),
      '/screen4': (BuildContext context) =>  Screen4()
    },
    onUnknownRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
            Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Not Found'))),
      );
    },
  )
  );
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Screen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Screen4 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

onUnknownRoute property is used to handle the worst case when the app navigation fails to get a route. If not handled, exception will be generated.

The navigator widget manages a stack of Route objects.
Route objects are nothing but full-screen elements like "screens" or "pages".
The navigator manages navigation between the screens in any app.
The Navigator for any app is only built if routes are provided by one of below items

> 1. [home](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/home.html)
> 2. [routes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/routes.html)
> 3. [onGenerateRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateRoute.html)
> 4. [onUnknownRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onUnknownRoute.html)

- If the app only has one page, then you can specify it using *home*.
- Else all routes will be in *routes* table including the *home*
- If a route is requested that is not specified in routes table (or by home), then the *onGenerateRoute* callback is called
- when even *onGenerateRoute* fails to generate a route, the property *OnUnknownRoute* will be triggered to handle the scenario. 
  We can handle an unknown route as below,

> ```
> return MaterialApp(
>   title: 'Named Routing',
>   onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoute,
>   onUnknownRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
>       builder: (context) => UndefinedView(
>             name: settings.name,
>           )),
>   initialRoute: HomeViewRoute,
> );
> ```

If unknown route event is not handled using the *onUnknownRoute* property, flutter may throw an exception

Comment: Maybe I've missed it in the flutter-docu, but this is quite helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is coding in routes -> Example

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Material App',
      // home: HomePage(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
        'alert': (BuildContext context) => AlertPage(),
        'avatar': (BuildContext context) => AvatarPage(),
      },
      ***onUnknownRoute: (settings) {},***
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertPage());
      },
    );
  }
}
```